# Mysql slowing down my application

Tags: c#, mysql

my application is taking ages to load because of my database isnt located on my computer.. Anyone have any idea to how improve my performance?

```
    public Form1()
    {
        Splash splash = new Splash();
        splash.Show();
        InitializeComponent();
        Load();

    public void Load()
    {
        db.SelectTeam();
        db.SelectMatches();
    }
```

On db.SelectTeam and SelectMatches I get everything I need from mysql and put into lists...
Sorry if it's confusing, but I don't know what to do, and sorry for my bad english

EDIT: 
Here are the querys
 string query = "SELECT * FROM teams ORDER BY name";
 string query = "SELECT * FROM matches ORDER BY date ASC";

EDIT2:

I guess the big problem is my database located on a free host outside my country. When I test in my local db there's no problems

Comment: Perhaps you are loading more information than you need to.  Why don't you show us the actual database queries?

Comment: have you optimized your queries and checked if proper indexes are in place?

Comment: How big are your tables? Unless you have issues in the network level or are transmitting a ton of data, I would be surprised if Load() blocked for long. Can you load data asynchronously and update your display as new information comes in?

Comment: @ItzWarty, I think you're right, but a table called "matches" could in principle be pretty large.  Needless to say, the OP has not provided nearly enough information for anyone to help.

Comment: I guess the big problem is my database located on a free host outside my country. When I test in my local db there's no problems..

Comment: @Kirk Woll, that table is supposed to be big, but it isn't yet, i have only 30 lines in it

Answer (score 0):

There are two actions:
1 try to add index on the name and date columns
2 if the dataset is too large, you can try to read the db in another thread, in which way will not affect the display and interactive with users.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer! I'm trying to use thread but I can't make it work..I tried this way          
public Form1()
        {
            Splash splash = new Splash();
            splash.Show();
            InitializeComponent();
            thrd = new Thread(Load);
            thrd.Start()